# Makefile - Deduce targets from sources (on iSeries system)

Tags: makefile, ibm-midrange

On an IBM i system, using [PASE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzalf%2Frzalfintro.htm) (AIX emulator), i try to compile RPG sources using a makefile.

I have RPG sources and try to build a PGM program.
Every single source will be compile in a distinct PGM.

Here is the syntax i tried first

```
VPATH=.
SYSTEM=system -iv
CRTRPGMOD=CRTRPGMOD
BIN_LIB=MR_CH
CURRENT_PATH=/currentPath #${PWD} doesn't work

#With this line active, it works
SRC_RPGLE = src1.rpgle src2.rpgle
#With this line active, it doesn't work
#SRC_RPGLE = $(shell echo *.rpgle) #Should list every sources i want to compile
TARGETS   = $(SRC_RPGLE:.rpgle=.rpgleMod) #Should list every program i want to build

.SUFFIXES: .rpgle .rpgleMod

.rpgle.rpgleMod:
    $(SYSTEM) "$(CRTRPGMOD) MODULE($(BIN_LIB)/$(*F)) SRCSTMF('$(CURRENT_PATH)/$<')" > $(*F)_1_crtrpgmod.log
    ln -fs $(*F).rpgMod

all: $(TARGETS)
```

I tried to apply [GNU shell syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) using [AIX make command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds3%2Fmake.htm)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm confused, are you running IBM i or AIX?  Both OSs are supported on current POWER hardware.  Your title says iSeries (aka IBM i) but your post says AIX.  Are you using the built in PASE environment in IBM i by chance?  That is not exactly the same as AIX.

Comment: Yes, i am running PASE. Sorry for the inaccuracy. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the AIX implementation of `make` but assuming that the linked man page is all there is to it, then it looks like a bare-bones implementation of POSIX `make` (for an older POSIX spec).

Therefore, the only way to do what you want (expand a list of files) is to use recursion, so that you get access to the shell, like this:

```
SYSTEM=system -iv
CRTRPGMOD=CRTRPGMOD
BIN_LIB=MR_CH
CURRENT_PATH=/currentPath
CURRENT_PATH=/home/CHARLES/Projets/MRSRC/tmp

recurse:
        $(MAKE) all SRC_RPGLE="`echo *.rpgle`"

TARGETS   = $(SRC_RPGLE:.rpgle=.rpgleMod)

.SUFFIXES: .rpgle .rpgleMod

.rpgle.rpgleMod:
        $(SYSTEM) "$(CRTRPGMOD) MODULE($(BIN_LIB)/$(*F)) SRCSTMF('$(CURRENT_PATH)/$<')" > $(*F)_1_crtrpgmod.log
        ln -fs $(*F).rpgMod

all: $(TARGETS)
```

The `recurse` rule MUST be the first target in the makefile.  Also this won't help if you want to run other targets like `make foobar`; it will only help you run `all` properly.

Alternatively you can obtain GNU make and build it for your system, and use that.  In the end that might be a more straightforward approach.

Comment: In line with @MadScientist idea of getting GNU make, IBM does offer the IBM tools for Developers for IBM i PPRQ (5799-PTL) that includes gmake v3.77 (as of this post) .  You can find the PPRQ here: http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_porting_tools_index#LOT